# How can I display specific image in array of random images

Tags: javascript

I have working javascipt code that displays a random image from array of images after clicking on card. There are 3 cards and after clickong on each of them person will see a random image that doesn't repeat. My goal now is to ensure that person will obligatory see a specific image 2.jpg for example in one of these 3 cards and it will be displayed only in one of cards. Here is my HTML:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Card</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front" onclick="getCard(0)"><img class="img1" src="https://lp.rustaro.ru/wp-content/uploads/transformation/cards/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="back"><img class="img1" src="" name="randimg1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front" onclick="getCard(1)"><img class="img1" src="https://lp.rustaro.ru/wp-content/uploads/transformation/cards/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="back"><img class="img1" src="" name="randimg2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front" onclick="getCard(2)"><img class="img1" src="https://lp.rustaro.ru/wp-content/uploads/transformation/cards/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="back"><img class="img1" src="" name="randimg3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

And JavaScript part:

```
    // Turning images
    var images = [];

    (function() {
      generateCards()
    })();

    var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

    Array.from(cards).forEach(function(card) {
      card.addEventListener('click', function() {
        Array.from(card.querySelectorAll('.back, .front')).forEach(function(el) {
          ['back', 'front'].forEach(function(s) {
            el.classList.toggle(s)
          });
        });
      });
    });

    //Displaying different images on click
    function cardImg(index) {
      var cardNewImg = randomIntFromInterval(2,10);
      if (images[index] !== undefined) 
      {
        images[index] = -1;
      }     
      while (images.indexOf(cardNewImg)!= -1){
        cardNewImg = randomIntFromInterval(2,11); 
      }  
      images[index] = cardNewImg;
    }

    function generateCards() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cardImg(i);
      }
    }

    function getCard(index) {
      if(!images[index].valid) {
        cardImg(index)
      }
      document["randimg"+(index + 1)].src = "https://lp.rustaro.ru/wp-content/uploads/transformation/cards/" + images[index] + ".jpg";
    }

    function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
    {
      return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    }
```

Here is the link on a working [pen](https://codepen.io/MegaZef/pen/JqXyOO). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _“will obligatory see a specific image 2.jpg for example in one of these 3 cards”_ - when/how often? Once, on the very first click, after that back to “true” random? Or all the time when that card is clicked, same image #2 for that card all the time? And what have you _tried_ so far to achieve this?

Comment: He must see same image #2 every time after card is clicked, it should appear every time he reverses it, as you wrote - all the time when that card is clicked, same image #2 for that card all the time. I've tried doing it in if condition but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure that the first (leftmost) card is always nbr 2

```
function cardImg(index) {     
  var cardNewImg = randomIntFromInterval(2,10);
  if (images[index] !== undefined) 
  {
    images[index] = -1;
  }     
  while (images.indexOf(cardNewImg)!= -1)
  {
    cardNewImg = randomIntFromInterval(2,11); 
  }
  if (images.indexOf(2) == -1)
  { 
    images[index] = 2;
  }else{  
    images[index] = cardNewImg;}
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, can I achieve this with random card, not only first (leftmost)?

Comment: Of course. If you pre-populate the `images` array - for example 
`var images = [undefined, 2, undefined];` you will always have nbr 2 at second position. 
Alternatively, you can re-write your generateCards function like so: 
`function generateCards() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cardImg(i);
  }
  if (images.indexOf(2) == -1)
  { 
    images[randomIntFromInterval(0,images.length-1)] = 2;
  }
}`

Comment: Thank you again, but the new generateCards function seems to work as an old one, it doesn't guarantee that specific img number will appear or I've missed something?